# What is the correct way to scale a Flutter UI?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, flutter, flutter-layout

What would be the most correct way of scaling a UI depending on the size of the screen? I am seeing so many different versions of what people say is right or what is not a good way to implement such a thing.
I have been using a tehnique where You break up the screen into a 100 blocks and then use percentages to achieve the same "size" on all displays -> https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-effectively-scale-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes-2cb7c115ea0a but I also saw people using Expanded and Flex? Can anyone point me to the correct way of doing it? I have searched through documentation but I can't seem to find a concrete answer. Thanks!

Comment: You can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic approaches to creating Flutter apps with responsive design. `Responsive` means it adapts itself to different screen sizes:

Here are the two ways:

1.

> Use the **`LayoutBuilder`** class
>   From its builder property, you get a BoxConstraints object. Examine the constraint’s properties to decide what to display.

2.

> Use the **`MediaQuery.of()`** method in your build functions
>   This gives you the size, orientation, etc, of your current app.

For more details on building responsive apps in Flutter, check the link below, it leads to the `Flutter Official Documentation`.

[Flutter Documentation on building responsive apps](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/responsive)

I hope this helps.